Is the persistence of unseen objects evidence of an external world?
Recently, I was playing around with the idea of using Solomonoff induction and minimum description length to try to see if I have good reason to believe in my theories.
Of course, there are no hard set rules in philosophy, but the way this process works is you try to find the shortest/simplest theory needed to explain all observations, which seems pretty reasonable.
After coming across solipsism (the idea that there is only your conscious experience that is real and nothing else), I started playing devil’s advocate and realized that even if there is one and only one conscious experience, I can technically explain how one moment of experience turns into another moment of experience using laws of physics. The laws of physics would just operate on imagined entities instead of real entities, and conceptually, I saw no problem with this (like entities in a video game). Entities in my experience can be modelled without any need to posit their material reality.
However, suppose you are in a lit room and you turn the switch off. The light then dissappears. What’s the explanation of this? In the solipsism theory, you can still model “laws” in such a way where pressing the immaterial light switch “causes” the light bulb above you to switch off. You might even imagine the circuitry behind the switch as immaterial entities that “conceptually” work together to eventually turn off the experience of you seeing light.
But if you can’t actually see this circuitry in conscious experience, due to it being hidden in your sight behind the switch, how can a solipsist explain this process? The external world theorist can explain it by simply positing that the circuitry, the switch, and the light bulb are real, and that the circuitry “persists” in reality even when not seen. The laws of physics would then work with or “operate on” these concrete entities.
Does this kind of an example give an explanatory advantage to the external world theory over solipsism?
What about an idealist? Can an idealist who believes that every single thing in the world is conscious and fundamentally mind still explain this? If the circuitry itself is conscious, then surely it can remain conscious even if it is not in view of your consciousness, correct? And then presumably, the laws of physics can still operate and work on these entities, where every entity is conscious. Does this mean idealism can still explain this? If so, are there any examples that are explained better under a physical world theory than this kind of idealism?
P.S. I’m not sure what this kind of idealism is called by the way. I’m assuming this is Berkeley style idealism or panpsychism correct me if I’m wrong.

In a solipsist worldview there is no light switch to be turned on and off.

@MauroALLEGRANZA never said that there was. There is the experience of a light switch that is on and one that is off

Solipsism - I only know my own experience. Object Permanence is a feature of my own experience and a subject of psychological research. Researchers would not be trying to verify Object Permanence in infants and young children absent their own solipsistic experience of Object Permanence models of external reality. When I was young, my parents told me never to stick anything in the electrical sockets, and I stuck scissor shaped tweezers in the electrical socket! This caused a fat spark and tripped the breaker but no harm other than dread fright! Now I know (experience) models of electricity.

Notice you are trying to solve a problem using tools that form part of the problem.
The rule you use to determine the existence of something with a complexity of N+1 is based upon a simplistic logic of level N (which loads its own problems*). This is like assuming common pencils can draw in 3d space because they can draw in 2d planes.
Well, from such naive perspective (no intention to offend), let it be: yes. Which is more or less: since a pencil draws lines of any length in a 2d-surface, it can draw surfaces of any area in a 3d space. So, it is a yes that brings heavy issues, instead of solving the problem.
From the opposite perspective, the message here is that existence in such external world would be radically different.
* Logic which is, in addition, circular: you trust Logic ONLY because it is logical. This is a classic issue of Logic, remarkably addressed by Russell.


But if you can’t actually see this circuitry in conscious experience, due to it being hidden in your sight behind the switch, how can a solipsist explain this process? The external world theorist can explain it by simply positing that the circuitry, the switch, and the light bulb are real, and that the circuitry “persists” in reality even when not seen. The laws of physics would then work with or “operate on” these concrete entities.

Metaphysical questions whether the (or a) material world exists or not and whether solipsism is true or not, are irrelevant in scientific explanations of observations. Physics (or whichever other empirical science) does not assume, assert, posit or hypothesize that there is an external world. Neither does it assume, posit or hypothesize the negation of that metaphysical claim. You won't find that claim in any physics text book or any research paper.
You might find somewhat provocative claims like

"We know that atoms and molecules exist because we can see them."
(P.W.Atkins, Physical Chemistry (1986))

This is still not a metaphysical claim however. Merely a claim about what is observable. (It also doesn't target "reality" in general. The question whether or not atoms "really" existed or were "merely" theoretical constructs could once be seen as a metaphysical question. But since Einstein's explanation of Brownian motion it no longer is. Some philosophers may still challenge that, but I cannot believe they are really serious.)
You have to ask yourself, what is it you want when asking for an explanation? And what is it that physics gives us when it gives us explanations?
You perform an action, or you have the experience of performing an action, namely flipping some little toggle which you call a "switch". [Or was it more like a huge lever you pulled? Should I assume that that "thing" stayed in place after you "flipped" it? I don't know. Perhaps by "flipping a switch" you meant you closed your eyes?] [There is a huge danger in using those kind of facile, everyday examples in armchair-philosophy, namely, that you automatically bring in an enormous host of all kinds of background assumptions of which you do not know how they control or influence your ideas. The uncritical use of these kind of examples may be one of the main causes of continuous misunderstanding and confusion in philosophical debate; one of the main causes why philosophical discourse remains stuck in apparently unresolvable stalemates where what is "self-evident" for one is not so for others.]
You observe that after the "flip" action, it turns dark. Interesting. -- Is it? Well, let's assume it's interesting and surprising.
So, it seems natural to ask: How come? Why did it become dark? -- But how so? Why would this be "natural" to ask? Why would you want to know? -- Well, let's again just assume that when you encounter something surprising you want to know what 'caused' this surprising event. You are curious.
The "natural", initial guess then seems to be -- given this kind of story, this kind of framing of your experience, noting that nowhere you or I made any assumption about any external reality:

What caused it to become dark was my flipping the switch

That's an unsatisfactory explanation. First of all because it refers to you (me) as particular individual, but mostly because it merely refers to this one singular observed event. What we want from scientific explanations is being able to have a general explanation, a schema for predicting what will happen for any observer, at any moment in time (ideally). If so, a better explanation is:

Flipping this switch will turn off the light

That is a somewhat more general explanation, no longer referring to particular individuals and it's verifiable in future experiments. It still refers to a particular switch. [But that's all you got so far? Or not? Again, notice the tacit assumptions you're making. You're not really only speaking about this switch. You're merely "giving an example". You want it to apply more generally...]
Is that enough of an explanation? Perhaps not. The above is suitable for toddlers. But it might not be precise enough. "The light is on", "it is dark" is rather vague. Again, it doesn't matter here if you're talking about experiences/observations or about some kind of material, "objective" reality. Perhaps the observation should be better described as "A light bulb over there started glowing." Note that it's impossible to eliminate the 'should' in this context. It means: If you want to be more precise, if you want to give a more detailed description and explanation, then ... etc.
We might at some point in this process of making an explanation more precise or more general, imagine some theoretical entity that is not directly, as such, observable or measurable but that yet helps explain the surprising phenomenon or the kind of events that we want to explain. This is what Lucretius (and some other early atomists did) when he posited the existence of invisible atoms to explain how it was possible that (for instance) hard marble temple steps start showing the wear and tear of many shuffling footsteps after being in use for decennia. This explanation becomes more convincing when it also applies to very different phenomena (see his beautiful explanation of the movement of dust particles in a sunbeam, quoted in this wikipedia link). -- So, what is hidden in immediate experience does not need to be an obstacle: first it may be just imagined and guessed to be there, and finally, it might at some point be discovered and verified.

You see a plate in the room. You leave the room. You come back to the room and see the plate. Can you please explain why/how you see the plate still there without assuming that the external world is real?

"that the external world is real" is not a meaningful phrase, it doesn't refer to anything. How would you describe it's meaning so I might answer that question about a plate that I apparently saw? (And how would I even know you didn't switch out the first plate by something else that looks like a plate? Or that you didn't set up a holographic illusion there. What you are describing is not a physics experiment.)

We mostly interact with our environment without thinking and definitely without making any philosophical theories about it. If someone tries to prove like Moore "that the  external world exists" by holding up a hand and saying "This is a hand. It is real!" the appropriate reaction, if we would really take that kind of talk seriously, would be to wonder if we should lock him up in a psychiatric ward...

One way to get a better grasp on the questions you're trying to clarify is to read Wittgenstein's On Certainty.

actually, a person who doesn’t believe in the external world is more likely to end up in a psychiatric ward than one who does. Nevertheless, most of us unconsciously have philosophical theories when interacting with the world, like the theory that the world is real.

Both "A believes in the external world" and "A does not believe in the external world" are utterances without any clear meaning or truth-value. External to what? External is a metaphor - referring to the things "outside" our mind, analogous to things being outside our bodies. But the world is just as little "external" as the mind is "internal". These metaphors have no explanatory value.

So, I may be willing to continue this conversation if you are able to clarify what "A believes in the external world" possibly means and how and where we can find people (and verify we found them) that do believe this and those that don't. Otherwise, I've said all I wanted to say and urge you to first read up on several topics, like Ws On Certainty, or Other Minds, by John Wisdom, or about causality.

According to metaphysical solipsism:

In metaphysics, Metaphysical solipsism is the variety of idealism which asserts that nothing exists externally to this one mind, and since this mind is the whole of reality then the "external world" was never anything more than an idea. It can also be expressed by the assertion "there is nothing external to these present experiences", in other words, no reality exists beyond whatever is presently being cognized by that one mind. The aforementioned definition of solipsism entails the non-existence of anything presently unperceived including the external world, causation, other minds (including God's mind or a subconscious mind), the past or future, and a subject of experience. Despite their ontological non-existence, these entities may nonetheless be said to "exist" as useful descriptions of the various experiences and thoughts that constitute 'this' mind.

So at best "past and future" can be descriptions, but they may very well be descriptions of illusions. If time is an illusion, then changes over time are also an illusion, and so there is nothing really to explain. The "change" you want to explain is just an illusion of your memory and its contents, which are brute facts of your mind in the present moment.
You can think of this as a more extreme version of the five-minute hypothesis:

The five-minute hypothesis is a skeptical hypothesis put forth by the philosopher Bertrand Russell, that proposes that the universe sprang into existence five minutes ago from nothing, with human memory and all other signs of history included. It is a commonly used example of how one may maintain extreme philosophical skepticism with regard to memory and trust in evidentially derived historical chronology.

In this case, this would be the "no time" metaphysical solipsist hypothesis.

Time may be an illusion but the experience of time cannot be an illusion. It is undeniable the same way conscious experience is undeniable. It is true that if time is an illusion, there may be nothing to explain further. But if there is nothing to explain, momentary changes in experience becomes a brute fact, thus making solipsism explanatorily inadequate.

@Syed If brute facts make an explanation inadequate, then positing laws as brute facts to explain things is also inadequate. Positing a real world with initial conditions as brute facts would likewise be inadequate.

@user80226 but there is an explanation under the external world theory that solipsism does not have. This is why it helps to think of this through Solomonoff induction. In your case of solipsism where time is an illusion, how would you generate every piece of your memory? You would generate it by writing it out completely in a brute manner. That data is not compressed. Under the external world theory, you do not hard code this. The initial conditions + laws generate events in the real world. The laws + initial conditions may be brute but they’re shorter than writing down all memories by hand

@Syed "The laws + initial conditions may be brute but they’re shorter than writing down all memories by hand" - This claim is highly contestable. According to this source, there are about 10^82 atoms in the observable universe. If you entertain multiverse hypotheses, that number can increase exponentially quite easily. And atoms are not even fundamental, see elementary particles.

@Syed You also need to postulate empty space. It's also possible that you need to postulate a landscape of laws of physics, with different pockets of laws in a huge megaverse, according to the huge number of solutions to the equations of string theory. You may need to postulate all that as brute facts. In contrast, under metaphysical solipsism, you just need to posit the qualia you are perceiving right now, and that's it. I fail to see how you need to posit less brute facts.

your qualia is changing at every moment so that’s a lot of qualia, over time, with each and every speck of that qualia being a complete brute fact, unlike the external world. And even if you think there’s only one moment and time is an illusion, each and every memory, within which each and every speck, is a completely brute fact.

@Syed "your qualia is changing at every moment so that’s a lot of qualia, over time" - Again, this is an illusion based on your memory. "with each and every speck of that qualia being a complete brute fact, unlike the external world" - With an external world each photon hitting your retina can be traced back to the gazillions of brute facts you need to posit as starting conditions of the megaverse.

@Syed "And even if you think there’s only one moment and time is an illusion, each and every memory, within which each and every speck, is a completely brute fact." - Which, again, are much fewer than the gazillions of brute facts you have postulate for the megaverse/multiverse. Under solipsism, you only need to posit brute facts for the memories in your consciousness right now.

@Syed Under physicalism, you need to posit all the photons hitting your retina and all the atoms in your brain creating the brain state being mapped to your conscious experience, and trace all of that back to brute facts as starting conditions of the megaverse, plus all of the other possibly infinite number of starting conditions of the megaverse which are also brute facts (if the multiverse turns out to be infinite).

@Syed Moreover, under physicalism, if the universe is not deterministic but random due to quantum randomness, then you need to factor all the brute facts associated with random events into the complexity of your worldview, since there is no explanation for random events. You cannot compress random events with laws.

@user80266 So you actually don’t need to posit every single photon. That comes as a consequence of the right kind of initial conditions and laws. Secondly, let’s assume a single universe model since there’s no evidence that there is a multiverse yet. So you have initial conditions which include the singularity for example and physical laws. That’s it. This then evolves deterministically or indeterminsitically depending on which version of QM is true

@user80266 Now, as for solipsism, note that before we compare theories, we must agree on the data. For example, if you are saying that time is an illusion, and we only want to consider all of conscious experience and all your memories at that particular time, so be it. But that is the only data we must now consider with respect to the external world. And all of that data is generated through the initial conditions at the singularity and physical laws. Thus, the data is compressed more under the external world theory

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Syed Detailed replies available in the chat above.
